# Nothing on my page with an exception of the header after SQL query and table

Tags: php, sql

I've been troubleshooting for a while now, and I really can't find any answer. Basically this is what it looks like:

When I type the name of a real user: Nothing posted on the page with an exception of the header
When I type a fake user: User has not been found (direct translation from Norwegian in the code)

```
<?php
include_once("moduler/head.php");

$user = $_GET['user'];

$query1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE name='$user'");
echo $con->error;

if ($query1->num_rows == 0) {
        echo "<h1>Ingen spiller funnet med: $user.</h1>";
        return;
}

while ($row == mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        $styrkeLvl = $row['styrke'];
        $beskyttelseLvl = $row['beskyttelse'];
        $bueskytingLvl = $row['bueskyting'];
        $trehuggingLvl = $row['trehugging'];
        $gruvedriftLvl = $row['gruvedrift'];
        $fiskingLvl = $row['fisking'];
        $kills = $row['kills'];
        $deaths = $row['deaths'];
        $rank = $row['rank'];
        $money = $row['money'];
        $donstatus = $row['donationstatus'];
        $lastlogin = $row['lastlogin'];
        $regtime = $row['registrationtime'];

        $rankName = getRankString($rank);
?>

<h1><?php echo $user; ?></h1>
<table class=\"userView\">
        <tbody>
                <tr><td>Brukerstatus</td>
                        <td><?php echo $rankName; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Donasjon status</td>
                        <td>D<?php echo $donstatus; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Styrke level</td>
                        <td><?php echo $styrkeLvl; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Beskyttelse level</td>
                        <td><?php echo $beskyttelseLvl; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Bueskyting level</td>
                        <td><?php echo $bueskytingLvl; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Trehugging level</td>
                        <td><?php echo $trehuggingLvl; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Fisking level</td>
                        <td><?php echo $fiskingLvl; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Drap</td>
                        <td><?php echo $kills; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Dødsfall</td>
                        <td><?php echo $deaths; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Sist pålogget</td>
                        <td><?php echo $lastlogin; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Registreringsdato</td>
                        <td><?php echo $regtime; ?></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Any ideas? I've also tried running the entire thing in an echo with no result

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to vardump your query?

`$query1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE name='$user'");
var_dump($query1);`

Comment: Please please please, don't directly use a GET or POST or any other unfiltered parameter in a query, it is DANGEROUS! Read about SQL Injection: http://php.net/manual/it/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I would, but there is actually no error. http://puu.sh/bpcVH/ab9bd45902.jpg

I made my own now though by doing this to see if it would give me any errors besides it: 

    echo $kak;

And this is the only one I get

Comment: Thanks for reminding me Marco, fixed it :)

Comment: Alright, I used var_dump as you said

`object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0)  ["field_count"]=> int(30) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Thanks for the help everyone, if it's not obvious already I'm kind of new to PHP (got some experience with Java), so I'm still in the learning phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your variables inside the while loop are only available inside the while loop. so you cannot echo them in the tables. so `<td><?php echo $rankName; ?></td>` will give you an undefined variable error. The same applies for the other variables you are trying to display.

---

To avoid this you should try to declare your variables globally, or put your table inside the loop.

---

Also the other issue is that as it is the code inside the loop will never execute because of the double equal (==). You should use double equal (==) for comparison and single equal (=) for assignment.

So you have to change `while ($row == mysqli_fetch_array($query1))` to `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1))`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5Kr0pYFg

Like this? Thanks for the answer by the way, got a bit further so now it posts the table data with an exception of the actual variables.

Comment: Yeah, that is better. So does it solve your problem or still having the same issue? If it solve your problem please accept the answer, otherwise let us know if you still facing the same issues

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.
-
http://puu.sh/bpefc/46042a85cc.jpg
-
It gets me further, but it doesn't really solve the problem. I mean,  it should have given me the answers from the database right or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just updated the answer, if you still can't see your values in the table try to do a var_dump($row) inside the while loop and see if it prints anything.

Comment: Thank you!

Oh god, after all this troubleshooting the problem is that I added an extra equal sign by mistake. I code a lot of java, usually in eclipse so I'm used to an IDE making fun of me whenever I do lol. I was troubleshooting for a good two hours before I asked here, anyways thank you very much!